# How to list users present in a group using SCIM implementation

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, scim

I am trying to list users present in a particular AWS SSO group, but am not able to do it. I am using [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/developerguide/what-is-scim.html)

If anyone knows any workaround this, would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on their documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/developerguide/listgroups.html you probably need to call /Groups and filter on members contains . You'll get the groups returned, but they will never return a list of members inside of the group.